# Irreducibility of multivariate polynomial implies irreducibility of specializations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, irreducible-polynomials, algebraic-curves

I guess that if a multivariate polynomial is irreducible, then any specialization (substituting a scalar for one or more of the variables) must be irreducible, since I don't know how else to explain (paraphrased from pg. 15, *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces* by Rick Miranda):

> a nonsingular homogeneous polynomial $F(x,y,z)$ is automatically irreducible . . . then each of $F(1,y,z),F(x,1,z),F(x,y,1)$ define smooth irreducible affine plane curves.

However, I can't help but feel that some specializations could "accidentally" be reducible.  Is there a nice way to see that all of the specializations must be irreducible?

Comment: If for example $F(1,y,z)$ is reducible, so that $F(1,y,z)=f(y,z)g(y,z)$, then homogenize both with respect to $x$ would give you $f^h(x,y,z)g^h(x,y,z)x^d=F(x,y,z)$ for some integer $d$. But I think your general specialization does not work. It only works when $F$ is homogeneous and you dehomogenize it with respect to one variable.

Comment: Definitely false.  Try $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$ and let $y = 0$.  Or $F(x,y,z) = x^2 - y^2 - z$ and let $z = 0$.  KittyL is right that this is a special fact about homogeneous polynomials.